# Using multiple data sources for an underscore template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, i18next

I'd like to use the [i18n](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#i18n) (for require.js) library to load my stored strings in resource files based on the user's language.
I have used [this](http://resthub.github.io/docs/backbone/internationalization/) approach, since I'm using both backbone and require.js in my project.

Let's say this is my template where I'd like to use the translated string.

```
    <h1><%= test.options.test %></h1> 
    <b> user_ud: <%= data.id %> </b>
```

The first line is evaluated with the data taken from the resource file. 
But the second line , is where I'd like to use data from different source.

(default resource file)

```
define({
    'root': {
        'options': {
            'test': 'Yellow'
        }
    },
    "en-us": true
});
```

now there is the part where I'd like to render this to my view.

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'models/model', 'templates/template' , 'i18n!nls/resource'], function ( _, Backbone, tModel, template, resource) {
    var TooltipView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : $('#test'),

        initialize: function(options){
            this.model = new tModel();
        },

        render: function(){
            var $el = this.$el;
                if(template.length != 0){
                    var compiledTemplate = template['test']( resource ) /// loads pre-compiled template ///         
                    $el.html(compiledTemplate);
                }else{
                    console.log(" [e] No template found. ");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return TooltipView;
});
```

I'd like to achieve this output:

```
<h1> Yellow </h1> 
<b> id: 14 </b>
```

but I'm not sure how do I put two sources of data into one template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `resource` and model data into a new object, which will become a root object used in template:

```
var compiledTemplate = template['test']({
  i18n: resource,
  data: this.model.toJSON()
});
```

And then access them in the template

```
<h1><%= i18n.test.options.test %></h1> 
<b> user_ud: <%= data.id %> </b>
```

Comment: actually the same popped in my mind right after I turned off my computer , I wanted to delete my question this morning but you were faster, ..your answer is indeed  correct. Thanks!